# jQuery nestedSortable, save order to Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I'm using a plugin called `nestedSortable` to sort the order of the list, with nested (`ul li`) to the Database mySQL.

However, I can't save the order when changed with this plugin. I previously used the sortable plugin, which does save the order to the database when changed, but doesn't have a nested option.

HTML code:

```
<div id="dnp">
    <ul id="sort" class="list-group">
        <?php
        try
        {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=uwv;host=localhost', 'root', '');
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM uwv_test1 ORDER BY Question_Order;";

            $stmt = $conn->query($sqlString);
            $stmt->execute();

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo    "<li id='id_" . $row['QuestionID'] . "' class='list-group-item space'><i class='fa fa-bars fa-lg'></i>&nbsp;"
                            . "<a href='#'>" . $row['Question'] . "</a>/li>";

            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $connection->errorCode();
            echo $connection->errorInfo();
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#sort').nestedSortable({
    helper: fixHelper,
    handle: '.fa',
    containment: 'document',
    tolerance: 'move',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'true',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    connectWith: 'ul#sort, ul ul#sort, #sort',
    update: function(){
        var order = $('#sort').nestedSortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "process-sorting.php",
            data: order
        });
        //$('#info').load("process-sorting.php?"+order);
    }
}).disableSelection();

// Return a helper with preserved width of cells
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) 
{
    ui.children().each(function() 
    {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};
});
```

PHP code:

```
$ids = $_GET['id'];
$display_order = 1;

foreach($ids as $id)
{
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=uwv;host=localhost', 'root', '');
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE uwv_test1 SET Question_Order = :display_order WHERE QuestionID = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':display_order', $display_order);
$stmt->execute();

$display_order++;
}
```

Whenever I use the plugin jQuery sortable, I have no problems with saving the changed order to the Database:

```
$('#sort').sortable({
    helper: fixHelper,
    handle: '.fa',
    containment: 'document',
    tolerance: 'move',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'true',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    connectWith: 'ul#sort, ul ul#sort, #sort',
    update: function(){
        var order = $('#sort').sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "process-sorting.php",
            data: order
        });
        //$('#info').load("process-sorting.php?"+order);
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Could anyone help me with this? I'm not good at explaining things, so sorry if it's not well explained.

Comment: EDIT: I dont have nested li's yet, first wanted to fix this problem

Comment: That's a lot of to write, and I don't want to spend about one hour writing the detailed answer. Instead I'll give you a hint: There must be a column, which is usually called `range`, and when you want to update the order, you need to update the whole tree on a table. Google about : *Adjacency list model* and simply implement it on top of nestedSortable

Comment: You really want us this whole mess to debug?